# Do I need to open or close the file to read the file through Node.js?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

Following function reads the file correct, but I am wondering if that's correct way to read the file?

Do I need to use `fs.open` & `fs.close` to read the file?

If not, In what cases do I need to use `fs.open` & `fs.close` ?

```
fs.readFile(dbWrapper.baseDir+path+"/"+file+".json", 'utf8', 
       function(error, fileDesc){
            if(!error && fileDesc){
                callback(fileDesc);
            } else {
                callback(error);
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to use `fs.open` & `fs.close` to read the file?
>
> If not, In what cases do I need to use fs.open & fs.close?

It depends what your requirement is.

[`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)

Returns the whole content of the file in the `callback`, this is simple and meets most of the people's need.

[`fs.open()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)

Returns the `File Descriptor`, where you can making further `fs.read()` calls using the file descriptor.

This is more complex but flexible if you only need part of the file.

Comment: Thank you very much, very well explained! @Neverever